# how to set next page rule with CrawlSpider?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am tring **scrape** email adress from a website. in order to do that i have to extract in every single link which is  in a list then on that extract page i will extract the email address.the problem is the nextpage button conatins upto 50. but if i change the url with a slash and input 51. it also go a new page.i want use for loop for next page link. as example i will use for loop from 1 to 999 it will update the next page url. below is my code.it's working fine as long as the next_page button is available.

```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class BestMoviesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'best_movies'
    allowed_domains = ['dastelefonbuch.de']

    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.dastelefonbuch.de/Suche/Textilien%20Gmbh',
                             headers={
                                 'User-Agent': self.user_agent
                             })

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths="//a[@class=' name']"),
            callback='parse_item', follow=True,
            process_request='set_user_agent'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(

            restrict_xpaths="//a[@class='nextLink next'][2]"), follow=True,
            process_request='set_user_agent')
    )

    def set_user_agent(self, request):
        request.headers['User-Agent'] = self.user_agent
        return request

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'email': response.xpath(
                "//a[starts-with(@href,'mailto')]/@href").get(),

        }
```

Comment: `rules` will be executed for every link the Spider go through (It will avoid duplicates requests by default) so there is no need to use a for loop.

Comment: The website I am scraping it have more than 50 page to scrap but when I am disabling Java script it's only showing 50 pages on pagination sector. If I am able to use for loop manually I will able scrap all the pages. Is there any way ? Please let me know.

Comment: scrapy automatically doesn't render JS, you can use Splash with it to render it Or go with the for loop instead of rule or finally Selenium

Comment: how to use for loop ? will you please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

Check your url in the start_requests function. It is not correct. I think you meant: "https://www.dastelefonbuch.de/Suche/Textilien"